# Typescript pasar de for a foreach

Tags: angular, typescript

estoy intentando pasar un bucle for a foreach, este es el bucle:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.art.length; i++) {
  if(i === this.art.length - 1 ){
  this.pri = this.art[i]['pri'];
  this.sellService.setA(this.pri);
  }
}
```

Estoy intentando hacer esto:

```
    this.art.forEach(function (value, index) {
     if(index === value - 1 ){
      this.pri = this.art[index]['pri'];
      this.sellService.setA(this.pri);
     }
    });
```

Pero en el value tengo este error:

> The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

Comment: Es posible que tengas un fallo con el contexto. ¿Por que no utilizas una arrow function?. Prueba asi: `this.art.forEach((value, index)  => {.......});`

Comment: Si el error te da en if(index === value - 1 ) prueba a cambiar a esto: if(index === (value - 1) ), puede que no pueda hacer la operación en una sentencia if.

Comment: Si, el error lo tengo en el value, haciendo esto sale el mismo error

Comment: Estás intentando restar 1 al valor del elemento del array, que seguramente no sea un número.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voy a asumir que ese no es *todo* el bucle y que por simplificar el escenario has quitado código, porque

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.art.length; i++) {
  if(i === this.art.length - 1 ){
    this.pri = this.art[i]['pri'];
    this.sellService.setA(this.pri);
  }
}
```

Es equivalente a

```
this.pri = this.art[this.art.length - 1].pri;
this.sellService.setA(this.pri);
```

La función que le pasas como parámetro al método `forEach` puede recibir hasta 3 parámetros, pero centrémonos en los dos primeros, que son los que estás usando: `value` (el elemento en la n-ésima iteración) e `index` (el índice o posición de dicho elemento).

- `index` es el equivalente al contador del bucle: `i`
- `value` es el elemento del array cuyo índice es `i`: `this.art[i]`

Por tanto el equivalente sería:

```
this.art.forEach((value, index) => {
  if (index === this.art.length - 1) {
    this.pri = value.pri;
    this.sellService.setA(this.pri);
  }
  //... resto del código en el bucle
});
```

Es **importante** que uses una función flecha aquí, porque en otro caso el valor de `this` variará y necesitarías una variable auxiliar extra.

#### Bonus Extra:

Podrías hacer uso del tercer parámetro de la función que pasas al método forEach de este modo:

```
this.art.forEach((value, index, array) => {
  if (index === array.length - 1) {
    this.pri = value.pri;
    this.sellService.setA(this.pri;
  }
  //... resto del código en el bucle
});
```

Y, como comenta @Ilsanchez,  el método forEach, aparte de la función a ejecutar para cada elemento, admite un segundo parámetro que es el contexto que debe tener la función, por lo que podrías no usar una función flecha de esta manera:

```
this.art.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
  if (index === array.length - 1) {
    this.pri = value.pri;
    this.sellService.setA(this.pri;
  }
  //... resto del código en el bucle
}, this); //contexto
```

Comment: En el caso de no utilizar la función de flecha no es necesaria una variable auxiliar para el contexto, el último argumento que acepta `forEach` es el contexto. `forEach(function(value, index, arr) {....}, this);`

Comment: @Ilsanchez Correcto, lo añado a la respuesta. Pero de todos modos fíjate en que está usando `this` para referirse a un objeto que no es el array para acceder a otros elementos.

Comment: Si, en su caso, `pri` y `sellService` serán indefinidos

Comment: Me refería más al `this` después de la función `callback`. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach

Comment: Casi siempre me olvido de ese parámetro... buen punto

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas un bucle para eso, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
if ( this.art[this.art.length -1] !== undefined ) {
    this.pri = this.art[this.art.length -1]['pri'];
    this.sellService.setA(this.pri);
}
```